# how do u give permissions to user www-data to rw a directory?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I want to give group access to user www-data on ubuntu for a directory.  What is the proper way? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo chgrp www-data dir
```

add -R if you want it recursive